# R: data.table function not working in package

Tags: r, data.table, package

I am trying to build some custom function in my package (`mypackage`) which are based on `data.table`. My files looks like this:

`DESCRIPTION`

```
(...)
Imports:
    data.table, magrittr, glue, png, jpeg
```

`R/dataWranglingCleaning.R`

```
#' @title Numerify
#' @description Try to convert each column of a data.table `X` to numeric (except logicals).
#' @param X Data.table
#' @return NULL
#' @examples NULL
#' @export numerify
numerify <- function(X) {
    tryNumeric <- function(y) {
        if (!is.logical(y)) tryCatch(expr = {as.numeric(y)}, warning = function(cond) y) else y
    }
    X[, (names(X)) := lapply(.SD, tryNumeric)]
}
```

Testing:

```
library(data.table)
library(mypackage)

X <- data.table(a = paste0(1:10),
                b = sample(c(T, F), 10, replace = T))

numerify(X)

Error in `:=`((names(X)), lapply(.SD, tryNumeric)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

However, if I just copy the function itself and run it in the console, than everything works fine but stops working when loaded from the package. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Do you have `import(data.table)` in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: or `#' @import data.table` with roxygen2

Comment: @Roland No, I don't have it. I thought that "imports: data.table" in the description file was enough! Now everything works fine, thank you!

Comment: This is not really a duplicate, as it asks specifically about `data.table`. I stumbled across some similar problem and the comments from @Roland saved me. My problem was about subsetting a data.table, but I didnt import data.table for that function, just in the Description file. It didnt find the column I wanted to subset. Also there is no special function from data.table to import, so I also imported the whole package and it works now.